# Python: how to share global states between classes and display them in the GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop, tkinter

I'd like to share **global states** (e.g. *is_online* or *num_items*) between `classes` like **services** and the **GUI**.

I'd like to be able to **modify states everywhere**: events, service init, etc.

Currently I store all shared states in `globals.py`, which can be modified everywhere. To display a state in the GUI in almost live, I just check the states every x seconds and update the GUI label.

It **feels very dirty** and as I'm new to Python I'd like to know how to do it properly.

This question is **not opinion based**. There should be a **convention** or  **best practice** that I missed. The topic seems pretty common to me.

Any ideas? Thank you!

**app.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
from gui import *
from item_service import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    GUI(root)

    item_service = ItemService()
    item_service.add_item()

    root.mainloop()

main()
```

**globals.py**

```
num_items = 0
```

**item_service.py**

```
import globals

class ItemService(object):
    def add_item(self):
        globals.num_items += 1

    def remove_item(self):
        globals.num_items -= 1
```

**GUI.py**

```
from Tkinter import *
import globals
import time
import threading
from item_service import *

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.render()
        update_states_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_states).start()

    def render(self):
        self.root.title("My App")
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        self.root.grid()

        self.label = Label(self.root)
        self.label.config(text = "Items: ?")
        self.label.grid()

        self.add_button = Button(self.root, text="+", command = self.add_item)
        self.add_button.grid()

        self.remove_button = Button(self.root, text="-", command = self.remove_item)
        self.remove_button.grid()

    def update_states(self):
        while (True):
            self.label.config(text = "Items: " + str(globals.num_items))
            time.sleep(0.25)

    def add_item(self):
        item_service = ItemService()
        item_service.add_item()

    def remove_item(self):
        item_service = ItemService()
        item_service.remove_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to store data like databases, files and so on.
For example, you can simply store your "state" in a sqlite database.

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to the sqlite database file
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create your table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE states (num_items real)''')

# Update the state (update num_items to be 999)
c.execute("INSERT INTO states VALUES (999)")

# Save and close
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The states like `is_online` are just temporary and should be stored only in memory to be resettet on app crash. I use sqlite for other data. :)

Comment: I see. Then you might want to check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes